# set Interval seconds is faster than, local time second

Tags: jquery

I made a clock, using jquery. it was good. now i noted that, the time is varying from my actual system time, while my clock starts it is good. in case if my clock run a long time, i am getting variation from system time.

my function is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('USClock'),500,500);

                var secondHand = paper.path('m 250,250, l 0 -200');
                var minuteHand = paper.path('m 250,250, l 0 -200');
                var hourHand = paper.path('m 250,250, l 0 -150')
                minuteHand.attr({'stroke':"#f00",'stroke-width':5});
                hourHand.attr({'stroke':"#0ff",'stroke-width':10})

                 var myDate = new Date();
                 var actualSeconds = myDate.getSeconds();
                 var actualMinutes = myDate.getMinutes();
                 var actualHours = myDate.getHours();
               // 

               var currentSecondDeg = actualSeconds*6;
               var currentMinuteDeg = actualMinutes*6;
               var currentHourDeg  =  actualHours*30 + ((actualMinutes)*0.5);

               var num = currentSecondDeg;

               secondHand.rotate(currentSecondDeg,250,250);
               minuteHand.rotate(currentMinuteDeg,250,250);
               hourHand.rotate(currentHourDeg,250,250);

               var update = function(){
                    num +=6;
                    currentSecondDeg = num;
                    secondHand.rotate(currentSecondDeg,250,250);
                    if(( currentSecondDeg % 360) == 0){
                        num = 0;
                        currentMinuteDeg +=6;

                        minuteHand.rotate(currentMinuteDeg,250,250);

                        currentHourDeg += 0.5; // 360/12 = 30deg per hour so per min 30/60 = 0.5

                        hourHand.rotate(currentHourDeg,250,250);

                        if(currentMinuteDeg == 360){
                            currentMinuteDeg = 0;
                        }

                        if(currentHourDeg == 360){
                            currentHourDeg = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    //$('p').html('SecondsDeg'+(currentSecondDeg)+'<br> currentMinuteDeg'+currentMinuteDeg+'<br>currentHourDeg'+currentHourDeg);
               }
               var myInterval = setInterval(update,1000);
            })
```

actually my question is why the set interval varys from long time process. as well if any one find the issue or wrong approach of work with my function let me know. Else, if any one know a good way to do as well appreciated.

thanks in advance! Any way to solve it, else how can i show 4 different clock in to my website? only way to get time from server?

Comment: `setInterval()`s and `setTimeout()`s aren't guaranteed to run with the literal timing specified, AFAIK. Javascript is single-threaded, so if the system is busy, it can be run later than expected.

Comment: Note, you would probably be better off determining the time as the `setInterval()` runs using `new Date()`.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval()` (and also `setTimeout()`) can be affected by the speed of the processor, the speed of the browsers' javascript implementation, as well as the load on the processor. They are in no way aligned to the system clock.

Have a read of [this page](http://www.goat1000.com/2011/03/23/how-accurate-is-window.setinterval.html) for more information.

Comment: I need to show the clock, then each time i need to get time from server?, that will make my system slow, that's why i updated from server and running from front end

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving setInterval a little too much credit - take a look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)

Basically, similar to a setTimeout, setInterval  "can also fire later when the page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks."